# htaccess-owner is www-data, is this secure?

Tags: security, webserver

I do write my htaccess-file by PHP and now I have read, that this is a scurity issue, because the htaccess-file's owner is www-data, when the file is created via PHP.

I also create a config.php which contains the mysql-creditentials.. this is also www-data then..

my question is, is this really a security-issue? how could this be exploited?

Answer (score 0):

If .htaccess is writable by PHP, as it is purposefully in your case, that means if anyone is able to leverage any security problem in your PHP code they may be able to write to the .htaccess file, which might give them even more leverage to execute more arbitrary code.

For instance, some vulnerable file-uploading PHP code is tricked into writing an .htaccess file which configures Apache to execute .jpg files as PHP; and then another uploaded JPG file which actually contains PHP code is saved into the webroot folder where it can now be executed as PHP code. Et voilà, arbitrary PHP code execution.

Another nice scenario would be a rewrite rule turning your server into a reverse proxy forwarding requests to some other server and lending a hand in some DDoS attack against a 3rd party.

The point is that your web server wields a lot of power with its configuration, and .htaccess files allow you to change that configuration, and allowing PHP to change .htaccess files moves that power and the responsibility to use that power correctly into PHP. Which means you now need to be 100% certain that there are no exploitable bugs in your PHP code which could lead to somebody abusing that power.

It's always better to segregate powers and give individual pieces as little power as possible. There are probably much better approaches for whatever you're trying to do there that do not require dynamic reconfiguration of your web server by programmatically generating .htaccess files.